# In fullcalendar.js, how can I set eventLimit to only apply to certain events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar.js, and have some events that I want to collapse (with eventLimit), but other events that I always want to appear on the calendar. Is this possible with FullCalendar?

If not, is this an easy change that could be made to the source? I looked into the events but couldn't see a way to easily specify only certain events for the eventLimit code to apply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work by doing the following:

When adding/creating the events, I inserted a new property for them called `isLimited` and set it to `true` (this property is in addition to the normal ones like `start`, `id`, `title`, etc). This allows me to define which events will be hidden by eventLimit.

Next, in the `eventRender` function in the config, I added this:

```
if (event.isLimited) element.addClass('isLimited');
```

I used this class to target the elements I want to hide. To do so, in fullcalendar.js, in the `limitRow` function (around line 4937 or so, at least for me) I changed this:

```
limitedNodes = rowStruct.tbodyEl.children().slice(levelLimit) // get level <tr> elements past the limit
   .addClass('fc-limited').get(); // hide elements and get a simple DOM-nodes array
```

To this:

```
limitedNodes = rowStruct.tbodyEl.children().slice(levelLimit) // get level <tr> elements past the limit
   .find('td.isLimited').addClass('fc-limited').get(); // hide elements and get a simple DOM-nodes array
```

Then, in the same file, around line 5204 or so, in the `getCellSegs` function, I changed this:

```
if (seg) {
    segs.push(seg);
}
```

To this:

```
if (seg && seg.event.isLimited) {
    segs.push(seg);
}
```

This makes the calendar only count the events with `isLimited` for the "more" link. And then finally I added this to the calendar config as a `eventAfterAllRender` function:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) { 
    $('.fc-more-cell').parent('tr').each(function(){ 
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()); 
    });
},
```

This is so the "more" link will always be on the bottom of the row after the other events.